# VoIP phone only works when connected through a secondary Eero AP. Confused

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, voip

A client reported one of their office VoIP phones was dropping calls within a couple seconds ever since they had a power surge at the office. When I arrived they also reported inconsistent speeds across their computers, flakey connections to their NAS and printers, etc. All devices are hardwired aside from phones and tablets. (I've attached a diagram of the pertinent components.)

[image: Network Diagram]

• First thing I did was reboot all of the network equipment. That seemed to correct the inconsistent speeds and as far as I could tell all PCs and network equipment were communicating fine now. Except the one Yealink phone in Office #2 which would still drop calls after a few seconds every time.

• I assumed the phone might have been zapped in the power surge, but to rule out any switches or network ports I first tried connecting the phone to my laptop, which I set up as a wifi bridge. The phone worked perfectly, no dropped calls! So that seems to imply the phone is ok.

• I then tried bypassing the 5-port switch under the desk and plugged the phone straight into the wall jack, it dropped the call that way too. But all other devices were working fine. So the switch wasn't the issue.

• I then took the phone to Office #1. I tried plugging it into multiple open ports on the 8-port switch under the desk there – all dropped the call within seconds.

• I then plugged the phone into an open port on the back of the Eero in that office – and it worked perfectly! The Eero is hardwired to the same switch, and all other equipment connected was working fine.

• Now it was getting late in the day so I didn't try connecting it directly to the 24-port switch or the main Eero gateway, but what I did do was take an extra Eero and inserted it between the wall jack in Office #2 and the 5-port switch and the phone has been working fine for over 24 hours now.

**Question:**

Can anyone shed some light on why it works when connected to an Eero or my laptop? My client is fine with it as is as long as it works (though I don't like it – too many wireless APs in a small area and it's an unsatisfactory solution), or they don't care if I replace all switches and get a different router to replace the Eero gateway. But I'd like to know *why* if possible. It's been 20 years since my CS classes in networking, but I'm guessing maybe the Eero is operating at a different layer that is masking some underlying network glitch?

I appreciate any insight or suggestions to try next.